# Treating Lower Back Soreness resulting from exercise

Tags: muscle-soreness, p90x

I started working out again (P90X Lean) about 2 weeks ago and after the 3rd day my lower back was really sore. I figured it was just muscle soreness so I continued excercise the 4th day; which made if feel better that day but made it even more sore the next day.

Anyway, I've been taking it easy for about 10 days now. It is slowly getting better each day, but I am starting to get very sick of the pain. It hurts to bend over or sit straight up in a chair. I can walk just fine and am certain it is muscle related and not anything more serious.

Does anyone have any tips to speed up the healing so I can get working out again?

Should I do some back exercises, or lay off for now? Should I apply heat or cold?

Mostly I've been taking it easy and laying on the couch (sometimes with a heating pad) has seemed to be helping it.

I know it can take some time for back muscles to heal, but any tips would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Check the answers for http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-it-healthy-to-exercise-a-muscle-when-its-still-sore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rested for about 3 weeks, then started doing some cardio (on an elliptical) daily for a week. Yesterday I started working out again and things seem to be moving forward again. I just need to make sure I don't overwork my lower back muscles again.

It just took some time of rest to heal.

Comment: I have found that often times I need to apply heat to expedite the healing process of sore lower back muscle pain. If injured too much you may need to ice it at first to minimize the damage from swelling, but then heat can help increase blood flow. Hot tubs work really nice for this.

Answer (score 1):

You're back is always going to be sore after workouts because some people hurt their back or back muscles and always will have soreness because they think rest will help and then they go all out again a week after rest. Some bodies are not made for intense training.
I could never use P90X due to my low back muscles. The angels of their movements just isn't for me. Everyone is different. I've talked to so many people that've overtrained in p90x.
Weak core muscles and stabilizer muscles could also be the cause. Good Luck.

Comment: Outside of some kind of permanent injury, everyone can strengthen their muscles, including lower back, and be able to do more over time