# How to get huge triceps?

Tags: muscle, strength, chest, arms, triceps

I have very weak triceps (15.3 inches) and chest (44 inches). I'm working out for almost 4 years but my bench press still under 154lb. The last few months I worked out harder on this muscle group, but I've barely made any gains. I added 0.19inch to my arms and 1.5 to my chest.

My chest day looks like this:

1. superset: incline bench press with dumbbells + reverse pullups 4sets 12-5 reps.
2. superset: guillotine(replaced with pullover due to shoulders pain apparently because I was doing guillotine. Maybe you have advice about this exercise and biceps curls.
3. superset: dips + reverse curls for brachialis.
4. skull crasher + tricep pushdown.

All exercises performed within 4 sets with 12-5 reps.

What can I add to my program for better progress?
Maybe you have tips?

Comment: How may chest days in a week?

Comment: If you train "drug-free", 4 years is not a lot of time.  If you want to see results, plan on making exercise a lifetime experience.  Additionally, make sure you are training all three heads of the triceps muscle.

Comment: @rrirower If an adult man trained for four years and had nothing to show for it, something is very wrong. There's no need to take drugs to see results within a year. I see no reason not to expect a 1.5xBW bench (for *most* men) and noticeable tricep growth in the time span of six months training.

Comment: What kind of weight are you using, and how often does it change? How many times per week — and how consistently, for how long? And do you ever do a plain bench press?

Comment: @dave-liepmann Normally I'm using 60lb dumbbells for incline bench press. Pullover 55lb dumbbells. Dips 8rep with my own weight(212.5lb)+ a few sets on gravitron machine. Scull crusher 40lb barbell. And triceps pulldown 40lb

Comment: @dave-liepmann Since October I've added 33lb to dumbbell bench press. Normally I'm doing chest day once per week. I'm using bro split. I'm thinking to change it on lower-upper full body. But I feel pain in my muscles(chest included) all week 'till the next workout. I perform a plain bench press 1 per month

Comment: I *personally* have not seen hypertrophy results from working a body part once a week. If that's how often you're hitting your triceps then try hitting them with at least one hard set every workout. What worked for me triceps-wise is a circuit finisher every day I'm in the gym: `pull-ups/rest/dips/rest/box jumps/repeat`.

Comment: @dave-liepmann What if I feel soreness in triceps and chest after workout 'till the next workout. Should I hit this muscle group again within a weak?

Comment: See: [Is it healthy to exercise a muscle when its still sore](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-it-healthy-to-exercise-a-muscle-when-its-still-sore).

Answer (score 3):

If you're not seeing results working a body part once per week, I recommend trying to work that body part more often. Soreness doesn't really enter into the question unless it is debilitating.

I have not personally found that exercise variety makes a big difference for most adult men who are relative beginners, like you and me and everyone else bench pressing less than 1.5x their bodyweight. Exercise *selection* matters, because you want to pick an exercise that is effective for your needs and goals. But once you identify that exercise, I see no reason to do a bunch of similar stuff. For instance, as a beginner my arms grew just by doing overhead press, pull-ups, and dips. (And on some programs not even all three.)

One key reason to focus on one exercise rather than several is that it lets you spend more energy in that one exercise. Four sets of 12-15 reps for four exercises means you need to spread your ATP across 192 to 240 total reps. With three sets of 12-20 reps (my favorite for dips) you can focus all your effort into making those 36 to 60 as heavy and intense as possible.

If your triceps are not getting bigger and stronger with consistent once-a-week training, try working them every workout. One exercise should be plenty. One challenging set might be enough, but I prefer two to five, usually three. Three hard sets of a heavily-tricep-dependent compound movement, done three or four times a week, a little more challenging each time (i.e. aiming for a few more pounds or reps per set each workout) should either get you bigger and stronger or tell you something more fundamental is wrong. Once a week is just not very much!

Answer (score 2):

Train your triceps close to exhaustion with the least boring exercise in your arsenal.

Eat based on how tired you are.

Sleep more if possible, sleep better by taking cold showers right before going to bed to lower your blood temperature and get your body into a lethargic state... Possibly also have a fat heavy meal to weigh you down. If you can, stay away from your phone for at least 3 hours before bed.