# Need some biceps

Tags: biceps

Categorically can't do pull ups or bicep curls.
I need something really hard to challenge my biceps, they are my weakest point and the hardest thing to train without equipment.

Comment: You can largely follow [some advice you gave someone else](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/43302/8828) for this problem. But as it stands, there's not really a question in your post, so it's going to be closed as "Unclear what you're asking" unless you focus in on a particular problem, and ask a clear, answerable question about it.